# Organizing data to use Graphshortestpath Function - Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, shortest-path

I know the concept behind *Graphshortestpath Function* in Matlab however I have to re-code this portion to connect the path again.

```
W = [44.35 45.84 41.19 23.81 59.86 68.63 29.99 24.13 47.3 30.36 500];
DG = sparse([1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11],[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1],W);
UG = tril(DG + DG');
```

Is there other way that I can make my life easier?? I have a huge data that require to input into the system and my data are in Excel format. I can't possibly re-code this every single time. Really appreciate your help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an way around, I have a suggestion.

If you have your data in Excel, you could import the Edge list in a variable for example

E=importdata('edgelist.txt')

And then import the weight in another variable as

W=importdata("weights.txt')

The rest is just using the commands as below:

```
DG=sparse(E(:,1),E(:,2),W);
```

Hope this solves your problem.